# How disable tests in scalatest?

Tags: scala, scalatest

[Here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide) is my test suite example written in scalatest

```
"my big test suite" when {
  "action 1 happen" should {...}
  "action 2 happen" should {...}
  "action 3 happen" should {...}
  "need to run" should {...}
}
```

Scalatest specification [provides](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests) a way to ignore test. But how can I ignore only `action 1,2,3` cases?
According to specification I have to replace all `action.*` names with ignore key word? It is totally bad.

Is there a way to put annotation (keyword) before (after) test name to disable it?

**Notes**

1. `action` - just name, actual test have completely different names
2. It is short example, actual code contain test with `in` key word (read scalatest documentation about it), so each `should`
   block contain several tests which are needed to disable together.

Comment: Either with specs2 & scalatest, you can tag some tests. Then the tag can be used to exclude some tests.

Comment: @cchantep From what I understand, Cherry is aware that you can write `"x" when { "a" should {"b" taggedAs SomeTag in {...}}}` but wants to apply the tag on every test within the `should`-block; like so: `"x" when { "a" taggedAs SomeTag should {"b" in {...}}}` to tag all contained tests. Unfortunately this code doesn't compile. My two guesses are that it can be done by either implementing a new method `should` or use a macro to do the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

replace `should` with `ignore` for target actions:

```
import org.scalatest._

class ApiHttpServerHandlerSpec extends WordSpec {

    "my big test suite" when {
      "action 1 happen" ignore {...}
      "action 2 happen" ignore {...}
      "action 3 happen" ignore {...}
      "need to run" should {...}
    }

}
```

BTW, `ignore` can also be used on other levels replacing `when` and `in`

Comment: I've rechecked and it works, not sure why it's downvoted

Comment: I get a compile error when I do this. Perhaps it's the older scala version I'm using, but could explain why someone downvoted.

Comment: Its scalatest lib version that matters. I use 3.0.0 version: `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"`

Comment: Hmm. I'm using `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % Test,`

Comment: Maybe it depends on IDE (Idea in my case). You can try to `import org.scalatest._`. When I navigate to ignore definition it resolves to `org.scalatest.WordSpecLike.WordSpecStringWrapper.ignore(f: Unit)`. And `WordSpec` extends `WordSpecLike`.